# How to cancel "moving messages" in Mail.app

Tags: mac, mail.app, email

How can I stop Mail.app to move messages?

I accidentally moved a thousands of messages from a local folder to an IMAP folder.
This will take a long time and will reach max space quota on the IMAP account.

I tried restarting Mail with and without holding the shift key but moving messages always keeps restarting as well.

**edit**:
Apparently it can be done by [deleting the imap account](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/299741/306606) but there are unsynced messages and I fear I will lose them by deleting and recreating the account

Comment: In the menu bar, go to "Window" > "Activity", in the small window that opens there should be an (x) icon next to the task.

Comment: Mac Mail Version 16.0 (3731.400.51.1.1) does not show an X icon next to activities for me.

Comment: A near duplicate : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/261533/can-i-cancel-this-neverending-message-move-in-mail-app (about stuck "moving messages", not cancelling it)